# Replace anchor tag onclick javascript function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which has a couple of anchor tags in this format:

```
<a onclick="javascript:RefreshPageTo(event, &quot;/web/Lists/exceptionlog/AllItems.aspx?Paged=TRUE&amp;PagedPrev=TRUE&amp;p_Created=20111026%2017%3a30%3a16&amp;p_ID=175\u0026PageFirstRow=1\u0026\u0026View={8AB948D3-7F13-4331-9F06-29C8480B1E80}&quot;);javascript:return false;" href="javascript:">
```

If you look at the RefreshPageTo javascript function it has a couple of arguments. The second argument is a server relative url. It has some querystrings, I need to append some more query strings to it.

Lets say for example I want to append the following query string to it: "FilterColumn=title&FilterValue=th". Any ideas how I would do this using jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML:

```
<a data-src="/web/Lists/exceptionlog/AllItems.aspx?Paged=TRUE&amp;PagedPrev=TRUE&amp;p_Created=20111026%2017%3a30%3a16&amp;p_ID=175\u0026PageFirstRow=1\u0026\u0026View={8AB948D3-7F13-4331-9F06-29C8480B1E80}"> </a>
```

Note that I used 'data-src' instead of 'href' attribute.

when document loaded, run this script:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    RefreshPageTo(event, $(this).attr('data-src') + '?FilterColumn=title&FilterValue=th');
                                                      /* concat what ever you want */
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer however i have no control over the original HTML. I can see what you are doing in your example, you are getting the anchor tag and adding an onclick event. In my case the onclick event is already added I just need to apend a query string to the second argument. I am not sure how I get the second argument and then append the stuff to it.

Comment: @user787427 actually I cannot get what you want to do here. Do you have 'FilterColumn' and 'FilterValue' as variables or what? If so, you can use global variable. Also, It can be run without external js file. easily you can just put the code that I wrote above inside onclick.

Comment: I managed to fix this by overriding the RefreshPageTo function. I get the two arguments, modify the second one and then call the original refreshpageto function.